# Main Query STUFF FOR XML PATH Not Working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have modified a script from MySQL to SQL Server and have mostly changed the script correctly but am running into the last little bit of syntax problem. I am trying to `STUFF FOR XML PATH` to a query at the top of the script after doing the same to a sub query inside the `FROM` statement. The sub query works correctly, it is the main query I am having a problem with. The whole script is rather large so I am just putting it on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/MVN85669)

I hope I am making sense in my question as the results I am trying to get would be having the `Complete_Codes` and `Incomplete_Codes` on the same line grouping the `facility_priority` and `facility_name` together.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Break down the problem into smaller components and ask a question about something more manageable.

Comment: This is the smallest I can get it. The only problem I have with the query is the main (top) query as the rest of the sub query works fine.

Comment: If you only have a problem on an small portion of that script, why don't you show us just the statement that doesn't work as you expect ?.

Comment: Not sure the problem with clicking the link I provided, but the main reason I didn't do that is because last time I just gave a small portion of the query problem, I was down voted like crazy because everyone wanted to see the whole script. I couldn't get the formatting correct to have it as a `code block` on here, so I figured I'd use rextester as I have been asked in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery using FOR XML PATH in a SELECT list of the GROUP BY query should follow the template

```
SELECT
    c1.facility_name,
    c1.facility_priority,
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + c2.Incomplete_Codes 
       FROM combined c2
       WHERE c2.facility_name = c1.facility_name AND c2.facility_priority =c1.facility_priority
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Incomplete
FROM combined c1
GROUP BY
    facility_name,
    facility_priority
```

So your inner query can be introduced as a CTE. Finally

```
WITH combined AS (
-- your inner query
)
SELECT
    c1.facility_name,
    c1.facility_priority,
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + c2.Incomplete_Codes 
       FROM combined c2
       WHERE c2.facility_name = c1.facility_name AND c2.facility_priority =c1.facility_priority
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Incomplete
    --, same for complete
FROM combined c1
GROUP BY
    facility_name,
    facility_priority
```

Comment: Thanks Serg! That worked like a charm. I will have to go back and review CTEs again as they keep coming in handy :)